# Filtering the dataview of a databound datagridview (with combobox column) makes it incredibly slow

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am facing what sounds like the same problem as http://www.windows-tech.info/3/fc05dcdb57f27f48.php, however, the workaround described there is not working for me (unless I've misunderstood it).

I have a `DataGridView`, which is bound to a `DataTable`, and also has `ComboBox` columns (this is important according to the user in the above link). I am trying to filter this `DataGridView` based on a separate `ComboBox`, but as soon as I do this it becomes unacceptably slow.

At the moment I have just this in my `ComboBox` change event:

```
private void cmbFilter_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    (dgvVolReport.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Empty;
}
```

So I'm not even filtering and even just setting the `.RowFilter` to be `string .Empty` makes it slow.

Does anyone know anything about this, how to fix it or a workaround?

---

Update: weirdly, if I call this line:

```
((DataTable)((DataGridView)sender).DataSource).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Empty;
```

in my `CellEndEdit` event, it does not make it slow so long as that line in the `ComboBox` `SelectedIndexChanged` isn't there. So it seems like it's the external `ComboBox` that is affecting the performance. Maybe it triggers too often?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible that your column auto-sizing is slowing you down if you have too many rows for the UI to cycle through. If you have the below setting (programmatically or in properties) then you might want to change settings. Try none. If that's fast, set it to use headings or only visible cells.

```
detailsDataGridView.AutoSizeColumnsMode = 
        DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
```

I'm not sure that's affecting you, though. It seems like the SelectedIndexChanged is being called too often. If you set `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` after setting the `datasource`, this can happen because it will call theSelectedIndexChanged event those times which is then iterating through your whole table again.

You could also use the `ComboBox.SelectionChangeCommitted` Event, which is less sensitive to things like databinding where you might not be expecting the event to fire.

Comment: `ComboBox.SelectionChangeCommitted` seems to have solved it! Thanks!